# The prepare() method is called twice, when the result type is redirect action in Struts2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, interceptor, prepare

I have the following action class:

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")
public final class FabricAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, Preparable, ModelDriven<Fabric>
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient FabricService fabricService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int pageSize=5;
    private Long id;
    private Boolean deleteOneRow;
    private Boolean deleteMultipleRows;
    private String message;
    private List<Long>chk;
    private Long deleteId;

    private Long begin;
    private Long end;
    private Long currentPage=1L;
    private Long rowCount;
    private Long totalPages;
    private Integer status;

    private Fabric entity=new Fabric();
    private List<Fabric>fabrics=new ArrayList<Fabric>();

    //Getters & Setters.

    @Action(value = "Fabric",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Fabric.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "id, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, message, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception
    {
        //Invokes, when the page is loaded.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "FabricPage",
        results = {@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Fabric.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Fabric", "currentPage", "${currentPage}"}),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError"),
            @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "currentPage", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String page()
    {
        //Invokes, when a page link is clicked.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Validations(
            requiredStrings={
                @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="fabricName", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, key = "fabric.name.required")},
            stringLengthFields={
                @StringLengthFieldValidator(fieldName="fabricName", type= ValidatorType.FIELD, minLength="2", maxLength="45", key="fabric.name.length", messageParams={"2", "45"})})
    @Action(value = "AddFabric",
        results = {
            @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Fabric.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Fabric", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "id", "${id}", "status", "${status}"}),
            @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
        interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError"),
            @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "id, fabricId, fabricName, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})
        })
    public String insert()
    {
        //Handles insert and update operations.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "EditFabric",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Fabric.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "id, fabricId, fabricName, currentPage", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String edit()
    {
        //Invokes, when an edit link is clicked.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Validations(
            fieldExpressions={@FieldExpressionValidator(fieldName="deleteOneRow", expression="deleteOneRow==true", shortCircuit=true, key="delete.row.reject")})
    @Action(value = "DeleteFabric",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Fabric.action", params={"currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "status", "${status}"}),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "deleteId, deleteOneRow, currentPage, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String deleteSingleRow()
    {
        //Handles deletion of a single row.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Validations(
            requiredFields={
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName="chk", key="delete.multiple.alert"),
                @RequiredFieldValidator(type= ValidatorType.FIELD, fieldName="deleteMultipleRows", key="delete.multiple.confirm")})
    @Action(value = "DeleteFabrics",
            results = {
                @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Fabric.jsp", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Fabric", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "status", "${status}"}),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Fabric.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs={
                @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "deleteMultipleRows, chk, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}),
                @InterceptorRef(value="conversionError")})
    public String deleteMultipleRows()
    {
        //Handles deletion of multiple rows.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    public Fabric getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public void setEntity(Fabric entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public List<Fabric> getFabrics()
    {
        return fabrics;
    }

    @Override
    public Fabric getModel()
    {
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception
    {
        fabrics= fabricService.getList((int)(currentPage-1)*pageSize, pageSize);
    }
}
```

<s>While performing all the operations except insert and update associated with the `insert()` method (both of them are associated with `insert()` which is mapped to an `<s:submit>` action), the `prepare()` method is executed only once.</s>

While performing either insert or update, the `prepare()` method is seen to be invoked twice. Why does this happen?

In case of `type="redirectAction"` in `@Result()`, the `prepare()` method is executed twice. Is there a way to prevent the `prepare()` method from being executed twice, when `type` of `@Result` is set to `redirectAction`?

Comment: Could you print an action name in `prepare()`?

Comment: How can an action name be displayed?

Comment: Something like `System.out.println("actionName="+ActionContext.getContext().getName())`

Comment: It displays the action name `Fabric` on page load, upon edit `EditFabric`, upon update, first it displays `AddFabric` and again `Fabric` and the same while inserting `AddFabric` and then `Fabric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake either choosing a result `type` or `location`. Because `"Fabric.jsp"` or `"Fabric.action"` aren't valid action names.

```
@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Fabric.jsp",
```

should be a `dispatcher` result

```
@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location="Fabric.jsp",
```

or `redirectAction` result

```
@Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", location="Fabric"
```

If you use `redirectAction` result type the new action class instance is created by default in which a `prepare` method is executed before the action. You can check this if you print `hashCode()` should be different even if different action names. So, no `prepare` method called twice as it only `prepare` interceptor in the stack of each action. On the other hand if you use `paramsPrepareParamsStack` the `params` interceptor is called twice: before and after `prepare` interceptor.

Comment: I have made these many changes but nothing is preventing the `prepare()` method from being executed twice in case of `type="redirectAction"` which is necessary for preventing duplicate form submission after a post request is made and `ActionSupport.SUCCESS` is evaluated in response to the request.

Comment: *no prepare method called twice*, as I told in my answer.

Comment: While using `paramsPrepareParamsStack` and in case of `type="redirectAction"`, the `AddFabric` action is invoked first and then the `Fabric` action as in the question is again executed causing the `prepare()` to be executed once again which in turn causes costly queries to be fired upon the database that should not happen. Otherwise, there is no meaning to use the `prepare()` method at all.

Comment: In other words, Given a `<s:submit action="AddFabric" value="Submit"/>` whose action is mapped to the `insert()` method with the result type of `redirectAction`. When this button is pressed, the only action which should be invoked is `AddFabric`. No other action should be triggered but in case of `redirectAction`, the `Fabric` action associated with the `load()` method is again executed as you mentioned, *If you use `redirectAction` result type the new action class instance is created by default in which a prepare method is executed before the action*. `prepare()` is going to be executed twice

Comment: I don't claim at all but I can see the `prepare()` method is not useful at all in this situation.

Comment: What you are talking here has no any meaning, the `prepare` method is called only once per `prepare` interceptor invocation.

Comment: I know it is off topic regarding this question. I will start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and what I eventually found is that I was referencing an interceptor stack in multiple places.  In your case, it appears you have at the class level:

`@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")`, which I believe uses the default stack.

And then at the @Action level, you have a reference to the `paramsPrepareParamsStack`:

```
interceptorRefs={
            @InterceptorRef(value="paramsPrepareParamsStack"...)})
```

In my specific case, my Action classes extended a BaseAction class.  I was declaring the `@InterceptorRef` annotation in both places. The BaseAction (first place interceptor stack referenced):

```
@Namespace("/")
@InterceptorRef("myCustomStack")
@Results({ @Result(name = "cancel", location = "${previousPageLink}", type = "redirectAction", params = {
 }) })
public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ParameterAware,
SessionAware { 
...
}
```

Then, in the action class, I had the interceptor ref ("myCustomStack") again.  Removing the interceptor ref stack in my HomeAction class solved the issue for me.

```
@Namespace("/")
@InterceptorRefs({
@InterceptorRef(value = "store", params = {"operationMode", "RETRIEVE"}) })
/*@InterceptorRef("myCustomStack") })*/
@Results({ @Result(name = "success", location = "home.def", type = "tiles")
})
public class HomeAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable {
...
}
```

And finally, here is my struts.xml that has the default.parent.package set to 'default':

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.myapp.action" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default" />
  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action" />
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default,json-default">
    <interceptors>
      <interceptor-stack name="myCustomStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
          <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
          <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
      </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
  </package>
</struts>
```